# R packages built under r-devel version?

Tags: r, version, release, cran, r-package

I was loading [AIMS package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/AIMS.html) and got a warning:

```
package ‘AIMS’ was built under R version 3.2.0
```

I thought `R-3.1.2 ("Pumpkin Helmet")` was the latest release so I checked on  [CRAN](http://www.cran.r-project.org) and couldn't see anything about a `R-3.2.0`.

Before calling it a typo, I googled the "problem" with different keywords and ended on [this page from r-project site](http://win-builder.r-project.org/) mentioning two `R` versions running, a `R-release` (`R-3.1.2`) and a "`R-devel`, to be `R-3.2.0`".
Googling "r_devel" confirmed what I was guessing, that this is the current development version.

I'm a bit surprised that packages can be built under the development version and I have a twofold question:
- How can a package already be built under a "to be released" `R` version and is it "safe"?
- Given that the development version is not released yet, how could I use the package with the `R` version it was built under? (Having a previous `R` version doesn't prevent me from using the package but I'm not sure I feel comfortable about the warning...)

Or maybe it was really just a typo?...

Comment: If you downloaded a binary, talk to BioC.  If you downloaded source, just reinstall with R 3.1.2 (aka r-release)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I installed it with command `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R");biocLite("AIMS")` (sorry, I'm not sure what to choose between your options...)

Comment: Do it again, but first start R-release (3.1.2) not R-devel.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm not on the `R-devel` version (I wouldn't even know how to install it actually...)

Comment: I wouldn't bother too much if I were you. This is probably a typo, or maybe the binary was erroneously built under the development version. Anyway, I can't imagine anything can go wrong. If you want to get to the bottom of it, contact Bioconductor and/or package maintainer.

Comment: @tonytonov, thank you for your comment, I'll follow your advice and use the package as if there was no warning and contact the maintainer if I happen to notice something weird. Thanks again for your time (and thanks for fixing my own typo! ;-) )

Comment: You are welcome! If you find something interesting, do not hesitate to post an answer for future reference.